# Never Finishes Final While Loop

Tags: java, io, locking

I have an assignment where I basically have to write a small botnet. We have been given a list of usernames and encrypted passwords. We have also been given the code to decrypt these passwords. The assignment is to use TCP to crack the passwords in a Master/Slave relationship. The password cracking is like a Dictionary attack in which you compare the encrypted passwords to a dictionary.

This means that a Master (Server) have to send instructions out to Slaves (Clients). These instructions are encrypted passwords, and where in the diciontary to start looking so that different slaves can check different parts of the dicionary at the same time, speeding up the process of decrypting.

Personally I have to take care of the Master. The process works as such:

A Master (Class) starts a Session (Class implementing Runnable) in a new Thread. The Session makes individual InputStreamListeners (Class implementing Runnable) for each Slave so that input can be handled on separate threads. When the Slave is done, all the decrypted passwords are sent to the InputStreamListener and added to an ArrayList of strings. This list will then be sent to the Session, and hopefully added to a list of ArrayLists (so ArrayList>). The Session do receive all the passwords. The Socket gets closed in the InputStreamListener and the Slave shuts down. This to me, would mean that the task for that listener should now be shutdown, and not be in the ExecutorService thread pool any more.

We have only been working with 1 slave at a time, so far. When the InputStreamListener close ends, the code looks like this:

```
try {
        writer.println("Disconnecting Slave...");
        scanner.close();
        writer.close();
        slave.getSocket().close();
        Master.messageServer("Slave Socket Close");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Master.messageServer("[" + ip + "]: Problem closing Socket for Slave: ");
        Master.messageServer("[" + ip + "]:" + ex.getMessage());
    }
    while(true) {
        Master.messageServer("Trying Lock");
        if(session.lock.tryLock()) {
            try {
                session.addResults(results);
                Master.messageServer("Added Results to Session.");
                break;
            } finally {
                session.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
```

The InputStreamListener reaches the while loop but only prints "Trying Lock" once. If it was locked this means that the Console should now be spammed with "Trying Lock" until it can actually reach the method and then print "Added results to Session".

The code in the session looks like this:

```
public void addResults(ArrayList<String> list) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        results.add(list);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The lock is a ReentrantLock.

This is of course done, so that 2 or more InputStreamListeners don't access the method at the same time.

I simply can't find out why this happens, and why the program won't work. Logically it seems to be working. Other than this, it just puts the information into a new method to create a txt file. Help?

Comment: how have you verified that the code stops at `slave.getSocket().close();` ? could it be that your `if(session.lock.tryLock()) {` is not firing and therefore causing an infinite loop in your while(true) ?

Comment: I printed a message when it got to that point. I have now moved my closing of the writer and scanner into the try statement, which makes it reach the while loop. Now, it only prints "Trying Lock" once, then nothing happens, even though if it was succesful it should write "Added Results to Session." :/

Comment: @AlexLynch I have now made changes to reflect this.

Comment: even with your edit, `if (session.lock.tryLock())` may not be triggering - meaning `session.lock.tryLock()` is returning false. this would cause an infinite loop in your code. i suspect it to be the problem. EDIT: you've said that "trying lock" is printed once, so this comment is incorrect :). you should probably place lots of print statements throughout the relevant code to see exactly where your code is getting hung up. you'd have to post lots more code for us to really pinpoint the problem for you - threads and locking are pretty tricky and you could have any number of problems going on.

Comment: @AlexLynch, if @Vipar is right, the infinite loop is into `session.lock.tryLock()`, this method is not returning so there is only one display "trying lock"

Comment: @AlexLynch
I construct an InputStreamListener like this in the Session class: service.submit(new InputStreamListener(slaves.get(0),                        offsetStart,offsetEnd,passwords,this)); the 0 is just if we only 1 slave. There is also a method to handle multiple slaves. "this" means the Session itself (I hope).